# Add elements one by one to QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like to use a for loop to search for elements and, upon finding each one, immediately add it to a QTableWidget. Specifically, the idea is that upon identifying the first element, it is added and displayed in the QTableWidget right away, and then the loop continues to successively add the elements found during the search.

This is part of the code and the function that I am using:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
        
        self.show()
                
        self.is_connected = False
        self.iq_option = None
        
            
         # BOTON GENERA
        self.ui.generarBtn.clicked.connect(self.generar_Signals)
        
    def generar_Signals(self):
        if self.is_connected and self.iq_option is not None:
            open_times = self.iq_option.get_all_open_time()
            if "binary" in open_times:
                binary_assets = open_times["turbo"]
                assets_open = [asset for asset, details in binary_assets.items() if details["open"]]
                expiration_time = 60
                signal = []
                last_time = datetime.now()
                for _ in range(20):
                        symbol = random.choice(assets_open)
                                           
                        time_diff = random.randint(4, 11)
                        last_time += timedelta(minutes=time_diff)
                        formatted_time = last_time.strftime("%H:%M")
                        
                        #elements.append(f"{formatted_time} - {symbol}  - 1M")
                        
                        hora_s, minute_s = map(int, formatted_time.split(':'))
                        end_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=hora_s, minute=minute_s, second=0, microsecond=0)
                        start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=1)
                        candles = self.iq_option.get_candles(symbol, expiration_time, 1440, start_time.timestamp())
                        if candles:
                            last_candle = candles[-1]
                            candle_time_utc = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_candle['from']).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
                            local_timezone = pytz.timezone('America/Caracas')
                            candle_time_local = candle_time_utc.astimezone(local_timezone)
                            candle_type = "alcista" if last_candle['open'] < last_candle['close'] else "bajista"
                            
                            if candle_type == "alcista":
                                type_operation="PUT"                         
                                
                            else:
                                type_operation="CALL" 
                                
                            # Agregar la señal a la tabla
                            self.add_signal_to_table(f"{formatted_time} - {symbol} - {type_operation} - 1M")                            
    
    def add_signal_to_table(self, signal):
        row_position = self.ui.generaTabla.rowCount()
        self.ui.generaTabla.insertRow(row_position)

        # Dividir la señal en partes
        parts = signal.split('-')

        # Establecer los datos en las celdas de la fila
        for column, part in enumerate(parts):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(part.strip())
            self.ui.generaTabla.setItem(row_position, column, item)
```

However, with the current implementation, all 20 elements are added after the conclusion of the loop. How can I achieve that the elements are already added during the loop?

Comment: Your code is executing in the GUI thread. The GUI will not update or respond to the user until you are done. You need to move your input routine to a [background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689800/async-like-pattern-in-pyqt-or-cleaner-background-call-pattern) or [periodically call the event loop within your loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518855/pyqt-qtgraphicsview-does-not-get-updated-within-loop)

Comment: From the look of `generar_Signals`, that for loop doesn't require any peculiar computation, meaning that it is probably able to complete itself in a few milliseconds, so even assuming that you *forced* the update of the UI during item insertion, there would be no real benefit; on the contrary, it will slow down the procedure unnecessarily.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to *animate* adding items to the table. That is, you want it to *appear to the user* that items are being added one by one, when in reality they are all being generated at once. One of the simplest ways to achieve that would be to move `generar_Signals` to a background thread and use a custom signal to send the data to the main thread after a short delay (25 msecs should be enough). It might also be possible to achieve something similar with `processEvents`, but the animation may not be so smooth and/or responsive.

Comment: Or save yourself the trouble and overhead of a separate thread and use a `QTimer`, where each timer event creates a new entry until done